# set password input on custom control label xamarin forms - Android render

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, controls, xamarin.droid

my target is set password input on custom control in xamarin forms on .Droid project.

my custom render code:

```
class MyEntryRendererPassword : EntryRenderer
{
    //CUSTOM entry RENDER PER ANDROID
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.SetMaxHeight(150);
            Control.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(255,255,255));
            Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(43, 50, 58));
            //Control.SetRawInputType(InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions | InputTypes.TextVariationVisiblePassword);

        }
    }
}
```

I have tested many codes that i saw online, but without success.
How to set Control label like password label ? I will see the dots when user writing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the `InputType` property, like:

```
Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationPassword | 
                          Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText;
```

Comment: Yes, that works. I'm waiting 10 minutes before check question on right. After 10 minutes i check the answer on right.

Comment: I'm waited 10 minutes beacuse stackoverflow not permit check right answer